# How to get the message content/embed from the message id discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I want to write a command in my own bot that writes the content of the embedded text to a text channel.
Unfortunately, so far I've only managed to do it for plain text messages
Can someone help me?
I am asking for help here because I am a beginner "programmer" and I am clueless.
Thank you in advance for your help.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'test',
    description: 'test',
    execute (channel, message, Discord) {
    message.channel.messages.fetch("902919303043637269")
        .then(message => message.channel.send(message.content))
        .catch(console.error);
    }
}
```

Comment: I advise you learn as much basic JavaScript as possible before using [tag:discord.js]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the message correctly, and it has almost all the properties (since it's fetched). You may however want to change `message` in the `.then` to something else (since `message` is already declared). You can access content and embeds with these 2 properties:

- [`Message.content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content)
- [`Message.embeds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=embeds)

Here is an example logging the content and embeds:

```js
message.channel.messages.fetch("902919303043637269")
.then(msg => {
  console.log(msg.content)
  console.log(msg.embeds)
})
```